# exclude CKEditor from pages of a specific Content Type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

What's the syntax to exclude CKEditor from a specific content type text areas ?

I know where to add the line to specify to not use it, but I don't know how to specify a specific content type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the CK Editor module you can edit the Global Profile in the CK Editor settings.

You can then disable entire content types with something like:

```
page@*.*
story@*.*
admin/build*
```

Both above demonstrate node type and path based restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how to do it in code, but you could use the better formats module (http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) to specify a different input format that is not attached to CKEditor for the content type you are needing.